# Order list not ordering by order_date

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created a page that lists all the items in a database that matches the logged in user, the problem I'm having is that my list doesn't want to be ordered by the order date.

This is my code

```
public function trackOrders()
{
    $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();
    $contacts = Contact::all();

    $orders = Auth::user()->orders;
    $orders->transform(function($order, $key){
        $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
        return $order;
    })->sortByDesc('order_date');

    return view('public.users.track-orders', compact('menus_child', 'contacts', 'orders', 'order_item'));
}
```

I've also tried removing this

```
->sortByDesc('order_date');
```

and adding this

```
->orderBy('order_date', 'desc');
```

but then I got this error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add like this:

```
$orders = Auth::user()->orders->sortByDesc('order_date');
$orders->transform(function($order, $key){
    $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
    return $order;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods on [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) return a new `Collection` instance and preserve the original collection. Therefore you need to assign the new `$orders` to the old variable, like:

```
$orders = $orders->transform(function($order, $key){
    $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
    return $order;
})->sortByDesc('order_date');
```